# Explore details of BizTalk 2010 orchestration

Tags: biztalk

I have few BizTalk projects created using [BTDF](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vercellj.btdf-tasks) for BizTalk 2010. I have `Visual Studio 2017` installed in my machine. To open these projects I installed `Visul Studio 2015` and `BTDF for MSVS 2015` but I still can't open the projects. Is there a way to explore details of biztalk orchestrations without installation `BizTalk Server` locally and/or older versions of `MS VS`? Some lightweight viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BizTalk server and project versions are tightly coupled to Visual Studio versions. Visual Studio 2015 supports BizTalk 2016 projects only.

For BizTalk 2010, you need Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Finally I installed `MSVS 2010`, `BizTalk 2010 Developer Tools` and now I can open projects.

Answer (score 0):

With VS 2017 I think there isn't support for BizTalk projects yet, but with VS 2015 you can installing from de BizTalk MSI only the Visual Studio components, you don't need to install the full BizTalk Server.